# Nginx 301 redirection from subdomain to domain

Tags: nginx, webserver, subdomain, redirect

I have a subdomain "subdomain.domain.com" and I want to do a 301 redirection when a 404 error occurs and automatically redirect the user to "domain.com". How can I do it? I'm working with Nginx Server Blocks and I have two Server Block files one for "domain.com" and other for "subdomain.domain.com". Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
server {
    server_name  subdomain.domain1.com;
    ....
    error_page  404 =301 http://domain1.com/;
}
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page

Comment: And all http subdomains to https subdomain?